# How to create a menubar in SFML application?

Tags: c++, macos, toolbar, sfml, menubar

I'm trying to write an `SFML 2.5.1` program, but I have faced an issue, I can't find in the internet how to create working program menubar, which is located upper window (or upper screen in `Mac OS`), something like this:

[image: menubar]

All I have found in the internet is a `Titlebar`, only first two options in menubar: `File` and `Edit`, and they are don't work for some reason, don't reacting on clicking, I can't find out why.

Help me please

Comment: Both Qt and GTK have implementation of sfml scenes in their windows. You may consider a backwards approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the original title bar and make your own using classes (`button` or `titlebar_button`, call it as u want) which is just a `rectangle shape` with the `on_Click` function.

https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24051.0 - Answer

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/namespacesf_1_1Style.php - Style documentation (I couldn't find one for 2.5.1, but it isn't that deprecated, in new versions, there is also a Style::Deafult)

Example:

```
sf::Window my_Window(sf::VideoMode(640U,480U),"w",sf::Style::None)
```

However, you have to keep in mind, that your window won't have any border and thus won't be resizeable nor closeable until you implement this.